# Python 3.4 If and elif statements not working

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.4

So the problem I'm having is with this part of a simple script for a Chat Bot about Programming. But when I test this part of the script and type in 'B' as my input, it says ('Panda: I'm glad you share my enthusiasm.') which is what is mean't to happen if I input A! Can someone please point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
invalidAnswer2 = true
while invalidAnswer2 == true :
    answer2 = input (user)
    if answer2 == ('a') or ('A') :
        print ('Panda: I'm glad you share my enthusiasm.')
        invalidAnswer2 = false
    elif answer1 == ('b') or ('B') :
        print ('Panda: I wish. I am actually British, but I dream of going to America!')        
        print ('Panda: *Cough* Um anyway that was rather unproffesional of me.')
        invalidAnswer2 = false
    else :
        invalidAnswer()
        invalidAnswer2 = true
```

Thank You for helping me fix it. It was a simple typo after all that XD

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Also in python there are no `true` and `false`, there are `True` and `False`

Comment: @BhargavRao Nope this is my first post on the site I haven't duplicated any posts.

Comment: @vishes_shell Yep just checked, pretty sure its all good

Comment: @vishes_shell true or false is defined in an earlier part of the script as I need it in a different way.

Comment: @BlackPanda then you will never escape `while` loop, because in `while` loop there is no `invalidAnswer2` changing.

Comment: The problem is that you have a typo "elif answer1 == ('b') or ('B')" should be "elif answer2 == ('b') or ('B')" just change 1 to 2.

Comment: @Nf4r Oh my god thank you so much how did I not see that XD

Comment: @vishes_shell No both true and false are defined. I've already tested and it does not infinitely loop. It works perfectly well.

Comment: @BlackPanda now when you corrected your indentation is seems ok. Because for the first time i asked about your indentation, you said all good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your that your first if statement  is always True:
    if answer1 == "a" or "A"
Will always yield true, because it's really asking:

```
if (answer1 == "a") or ("A")
```

And "A" will always return True.
What you meant is probably:

```
if answer1 == "a" or answer1 == "A"
```

or the better option:

```
if answer1.lower() == "a"
```

Comment: Another bad(!) one would be `if answer1 in ['a', 'A']`, just for sake of completion :D

Comment: Thank You! You were right, sorry for being such a noob X3